# Record count from query is wrong

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to look at three values from three queries. If any query comes up with a record count of one or above I would display the master form. What I have right now is the three queries and an if statement evaluating them.

The problem is all the if statements come back true. Even when I KNOW the third one is wrong.

I'm using the count function in the Access build query window.

```
Private Sub testCount_Click()
Dim strSQL1
Dim strSQL2
Dim strSQL3
Dim NoData

NoData = "False"

strSQL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT Count(GRP4100Deltas.[TCTO Number]) AS [CountOfTCTO Number], Aircraft.FullTailNo, StatusCode.TCTOStatus " _
& "FROM StatusCode INNER JOIN (Aircraft INNER JOIN GRP4100Deltas ON Aircraft.[Serial Number] = GRP4100Deltas.[Serial Number]) ON StatusCode.StatusCode = GRP4100Deltas.[TCTO Status Code] " _
& "GROUP BY Aircraft.FullTailNo, StatusCode.TCTOStatus " _
& "HAVING (((StatusCode.TCTOStatus)='Completed'));"


strSQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Count(GRP4100Deltas.[TCTO Number]) AS [CountOfTCTO Number], Aircraft.FullTailNo, StatusCode.TCTOStatus " _
& "FROM StatusCode INNER JOIN (Aircraft INNER JOIN GRP4100Deltas ON Aircraft.[Serial Number] = GRP4100Deltas.[Serial Number]) ON StatusCode.StatusCode = GRP4100Deltas.[TCTO Status Code] " _
& "GROUP BY Aircraft.FullTailNo, StatusCode.TCTOStatus " _
& "HAVING (((StatusCode.TCTOStatus)='Not Completed'));"


strSQL3 = "SELECT DISTINCT Count(GRP4100Deltas.[TCTO Number]) AS [CountOfTCTO Number], Aircraft.FullTailNo " _
& "FROM StatusCode INNER JOIN (Aircraft INNER JOIN GRP4100Deltas ON Aircraft.[Serial Number] = GRP4100Deltas.[Serial Number]) ON StatusCode.StatusCode = GRP4100Deltas.[TCTO Status Code] " _
& "GROUP BY Aircraft.FullTailNo, StatusCode.TCTOStatus " _
& "HAVING (((StatusCode.TCTOStatus)='Not Applicable'));"

If (strSQL1 = 0) Then
    NoData = "True1"
    MsgBox ("1 has no data")
Else
    NoData = "False"
    MsgBox ("1 has data False")
End If

If (strSQL2 = 0) Then
    NoData = "False"
    MsgBox ("2 has no data")
Else
    NoData = "True"
    MsgBox ("2 has data")
End If

If (strSQL3 = 0) Then
    NoData = "False"
    MsgBox ("3 has no data")
Else
    NoData = "True"
    MsgBox ("3 has data")
End If

MsgBox ("There were SQL without entries NoData = " & NoData)
```

Thank you for the help.
I'm working on getting some test data for you.
Maxine

Comment: What's with all those brackets?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but you don't seem to execute these sql statements... Is this VBA? Against what RDBMS are these queries written. Do you actually execute them but didn't share that code? And if so, you are using the same variables to hold your sql string literals to hold the results? Something is off here.

Comment: SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Tag properly by adding proper tags.

Comment: That's how they are in Access's SQL area. But I think I may have found my problem. I'm missing the run SQL command. Hopefully this will fix it. Added the execute statements but it's not accepting the SQL

Comment: After you run this sql, you are going to get back a result set. For your third SQL (for instance) you will get back many records, one for each unique `Aircraft.FullTailNo, StatusCode.TCTOStatus` combination. How do you plan to compare all of those returned records to an integer `0`? I think you have a few more dots to connect here.

Comment: I only need to know if there is one match. If there's one match then that item is true.

Comment: Got it. So you'll execute the SQL and then check the [count of returned records in the result set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/count-the-number-of-records-in-a-dao-recordset). That makes perfect sense! :)

Comment: Yeah problem is Access is not liking my SQL statement in code. If I put it in its SQL window it works fine.

Comment: I'm going to take a different approach. Have each query make a table and in the end evaluate if there are any records in it.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to this problem. Since all I was concerned about was if any of the three queries had one or more values. I changed the queries to update a countRecs Table. Then ran three separate append queries populating the table. Then I used a DCount function to count how many records there were. IF there was more then one record I new I would display the form.

Thank you for everyone's help.
Maxine